# Calculus questions

Tags: calculus

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to solve 9b and 10? I've been thinking for five hours, I really need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Notice $f'' = \frac{1}{x} \implies f''' = -\frac{1}{x^2} \implies f'''' = \frac{2}{x^3} \implies f^{5} =-\frac{2 \times 3 }{x^4}$

$$ \therefore f^{(n)} = \frac{(-1)^{n}(n-2)!}{x^{n-1}}$$

To see why this is true, inducte on $n$. This is routine.

For part $10$, Since $f$ is invertible, there exists $f^{-1}$ such that $f \circ f^{-1} = Id$. Now we apply the chain rule,

$$ 0 < 1 = Id' = (f \circ f^{-1})'(x) = f'(f^{-1}(x))f'^{-1} (x) $$

$$ \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))} = \frac{d f^{-1}(x)}{dx} $$

Verification of formula:

If $n=2$, then $f'' = \frac{(-1)^2 (2 -2)!}{x} = \frac{1}{x}$. Remember $0! = 1 \; \; (proof?)$

Now suppose $f^{(n)} = \frac{(-1)^{n}(n-2)!}{x^{n-1}}$ is true for $n$. We show this implies $n+1$ case is true.

$$ f^{(n+1)} = \frac{d f^{(n)}}{dx} = (1-n)(-1)^n(n-2)!x^{1 -n - 1} = (-1)(n-1)(-1)^n(n-2)!x^{-n}$$

$$ = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n-1)!}{x^n}$$

The problem is now solved by induction.

Comment: Thank you, I have solved 10 by myself. However, I am still confused about 9b, I cannot understand your answer and I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Just follow the pattern. compute $f^{(6)}, f^{(7)}$ are you will see they all follow a pattern

Comment: I think I can understand the formula now. But I am thinking how to prove this would be true for all n>=2

Comment: ok i updated the solution with proof

Comment: Your formula might be wrong, shouldn't (-1) have an exponent with n-2? Or actually, in this case for (-1), (n-2) is the same as n?

Comment: IS the same, it doesn't matter

Comment: OK, still one question, why (n-1)(n-2)!=(n-1)!. Sorry about this, I am really bad at factorial.

Comment: Never mind, I have just figured out. Thank you very much, you really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint for 9b:** You should look at your answer for 9a and see if you can find a pattern. If not, maybe compute a few higher derivatives - the pattern should emerge.

**Hint for 10:** Differentiate the function $f\circ f^{-1}$.

Comment: For 9b, I found the coefficient should be -1*-2*-3*-4*-5*....., but I cannot associate this with n

Comment: Well for that particular example, observe that $(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)(-5) = (-1)^5 5!$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f'(x)=(x)'\ln(x) + x(\ln x)' = \ln(x) + x\cdot \frac1x = \ln x +1$$
$$f''(x)= [\ln x +1]' =  \frac1x = x^{-1}$$
$$f'''(x)=   -1\cdot x^{-2} $$ 
$$f^{(4)}(x)=  (-1)(-2)\cdot x^{-3} $$
$$f^{(5)}(x)=  (-1)(-2)(-3)\cdot x^{-4} $$
$$f^{(6)}(x)=  (-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)\cdot x^{-5}$$
$$f^{(n)}(x)=  (-1)^{n-2}(n-2)!\cdot x^{1-n}$$

on 10 use $$g(f(x))=x$$ with $g=f^{-1}$ then take derivative on both sides.. on right side get 1 on left side use chain rule..

Comment: Oh,I see, I am really bad at using factorials so I couldn't come up with this formula. Thank you very much. But for the proof part, should I use induction?

Comment: I now understand your formula, but I still don't know how to prove it. Should I use induction?

Comment: yes induction will work..but start with n=2